# How to make a navigator extension for VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-studio-extensions

I am working on a C++ project using VS2010 sp1.

To jump between functions, we can use navigator list of Method and click at the desired one.
But in my project, there is a finite state machine, and I have to jump between tens of "**case:**" under a "**switch**". cases are not listed in any navigator that I have seen.

I tried to use the bookmark provided by Visual Studio, but I have to add it manually, and the bookmarks become more and more inaccurate as I am coding.

I tried to use Ctrl+F, but I cannot remember all those case names, and the editbox doesn't give any hint as I type.

Are there any navigator extension that lists all the cases?
If not, I guess I'll have to make my own extension, are there any related sample code I can follow?

Thank you